# Signal not received by bash script run using system(3)

Tags: bash

I have a bash script which waits for 3 mins before signaling a daemon.
During these 3 mins, I need it to exit if it receives `SIGINT`.

My current script works when run from the bash, however, when I run it from within another (C) program using the `system()` call, it doesn't `exit` when it is sent `SIGINT`.

Here's my current script:

```
#!/bin/bash

trap 'exit' INT
sleep 180 &
wait
trap '' INT

/etc/init.d/myd sync
```

Here's how I'm running it:

```
kill -INT `pgrep myscript.sh` 2>/dev/null; ! pgrep -x "myscript.sh" > /dev/null && /opt/my/scripts/myscript.sh &
```

The same one liner, when run using the `system()` call, doesn't work.

PS:
Basically, I'm using this mechanism to run the `/etc/init.d/myd sync` command after only the last time it is called if it is called multiple times within 3 minutes.

#### EDIT 1

The C code as requested:

```
system("kill -INT `pgrep myscript.sh` 2>/dev/null; ! pgrep -x \"myscript.sh\" > /dev/null && /opt/my/scripts/myscript.sh &");
```

The C program is quite huge (spanning tens of files), so I'm only pasting here the specific call. The program is supposed to run as a daemon, but I get this problem even when I don't run it as a daemon (using a command line switch).

I'm able to reproduce this with the following trivial C code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    system("kill -INT `pgrep myscript.sh` 2>/dev/null; ! pgrep -x \"myscript.sh\" > /dev/null && /opt/my/scripts/myscript.sh &");        
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you show the c code you use to execute the command.

Comment: I updated my answer with the C code. Could you please have a look?

Comment: Instead of `kill -INT $(pgrep...` why not just use `pkill -INT myscript.sh`?

Comment: I had stopped using `pkill` because it wouldn't work for long process command names. But you're right, it is appropriate here.

Comment: Could it be that the script is running in a shell that is not bash? What happens when you run it as `/bin/bash /path/to/script.sh` ?

Comment: I just checked... `ps ax` shows that `myscript.sh` is running in bash `9258 pts/0    S      0:00 /bin/bash /opt/my/scripts/myscript.sh`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The why (Updated):

- The actual process name is `bash`, not `myscript.sh`
- pgrep can match itself via `sh` in the `system()` call
- **SIGINT** just doesn't play nice when the script is run in the background.  (Have used SIGUSR1 instead)

---

After some discussion and testing on various OS, once weeding out the subtleties, this really came down to:

1. When starting the script from a tty, `ps` would show this:

```
46694 s001  S+     0:00.01 /bin/bash /opt/my/scripts/myscript.sh
```

2. When starting the script from the `system()` call (via `sh`), `ps` would show this:

```
46796 s002  S      0:00.00 /bin/bash /opt/my/scripts/myscript.sh
```

From the `ps` manual:

- > - ```
  >   state   The first character indicates the run state of the process: 
  >
  >       S   Marks a process that is sleeping for less than about 20 seconds
  >
  >           Additional characters after these, if any, 
  >           indicate additional state information:
  >
  >       +   The process is in the foreground process group of its control terminal.
  >   ```

So the processes without the **+** weren't playing with SIGINT.

It turns out we can trap **SIGUSR1** instead and send it **`kill -USR1`**

---

### Working test on Ubuntu 16.04 & Mac OS X 10.12:

**cmon.c**

- ```
  #include 
  int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  system("mypid=`cat /opt/my/scripts/myscript.pid` ; ps -p $mypid > /dev/null && kill -USR1 $mypid 2>/dev/null ; mypid=`cat /opt/my/scripts/myscript.pid` ; ps -p $mypid > /dev/null || /opt/my/scripts/myscript.sh &");
  return 0;
  }
  ```

**/opt/my/scripts/myscript.sh**

- ```
  #!/bin/bash
  #process for this instance of bash
  bashpid="$$"

  #ensure single instance
  mypid="$(cat "$(dirname "$0")/myscript.pid" 2>/dev/null)"
  ps -p $mypid &> /dev/null && (echo "already running, now going to exit this instance" ; echo "seems we never see this message, that's good, means the system() call is only spawning a new instance if there's no process match." ; kill -9 "$bashpid")

  #set pidfile for this instance
  echo "$bashpid" > "$(dirname "$0")/myscript.pid"

  trap 'echo "BYE" ; exit' SIGUSR1
  sleep 5 & # 30 seconds for testing
  wait
  trap '' SIGUSR1

  echo "Sitting here in limbo land" & while true ; do sleep 5 ; done
  ```

---

#### Testing

Simple line to loop the `./cmon` binary and check that we get a different process each time (whilst inside the timeout window):

```
unset i ; until [[ i -eq 5 ]] ; do ./cmon ; ps ax | grep bash.*myscript.sh | grep -v grep | awk -F ' ' '{print $1 " " $6}' ; sleep 1 ; (( i ++ )) ; done
```

Same line can be run once the timeout expires, to check all the process numbers are the same

A paste-able full unit test build and test sequence can be found here:
**[ybin link](https://ybin.me/p/713effa2a366bbd0#KST2gyJuc8dkIX5MIgBHACzETyn9KkBfFFwbDbBllAM=)**

And a demo of it running here:

[image]

**Notes about the process**:

- The scripts are modified only for ease of testing (i.e. 10 second timeout window).
- Single instance checking added redundantly (the single instance trigger in the myscript.sh file should never be triggered.. and never seems to be)

Update to follow when OP confirms final working

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to debug this. 
Here are a couple of observations: firstly, I don't see the long command name in my process tree as you seem to find. In fact, after running the C code, `ps ax` shows that `myscript.sh` is running in bash - (`9258 pts/0 S 0:00 /bin/bash /opt/my/scripts/myscript.sh`), and I'm actually able to get the pid of `myscript` using `pgrep myscript.sh`.
Secondly, the command tries to send `SIGINT` to `myscript.sh`, then checks if it terminated, and if it did, it then starts it (i.e. `myscript.sh`) again.

Comment: @Zaxter thanks for the info.  I can see that now with the ;   So my else statement should really just be another check.  Regardless.  With the trivial example, I couldn't get a SIGINT to go to the script, but with my example here I was able to.  What OS is this?  When I get back to my lab I'll give it a go on the same OS if not already solved.

Comment: @Zaxter could you let me know if my modified `system()` call works ?  The alternate solution is just thinking out loud and may or may not be suitable for your circumstance.

Comment: Thank you for your efforts @hmedia. Much appreciated...
Apologies for the late reply. I have tried your script on both my dev system (Ubuntu 16.04) and my target (Armbian running on a banana pi variant). 
Sadly, `SIGINT` isn't received by `myscript.sh` on both systems. 
But, I think your observations about the `system()` call running the script using `sh -c` being the root cause of this problem is spot-on.
This is supported by the fact that when I run `myscript.sh` as `sh -c '/opt/my/scripts/myscript.sh'`, I'm not able to send it a `SIGINT` even  using its pid explicitly.

Comment: I'm accepting your answer as it answers my question as it was initially framed. My specific problem though may have something to do with armbian, so I will ask on their forums.

Comment: @Zaxter Thanks, I was just trying this on ubuntu 16.04  Again, no problems, this has the benefit of being "out of the box" too.  Is there a way to get a discussion room to debug this ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144416/discussion-between-hmedia1-and-zaxter).

Comment: @Zaxter Glad to hear that.  Do you mind me asking out of curiosity (since this had a number of mods for testing purposes) what the exact system() line you ended up *actually* deploying this with ?